# problems to take percentage of an array and find the location with the function find()

Tags: matlab

I have some data points and I would like to get for example points which are 2% below the maximum. I am getting the maximum using

```
[peakVal, peakLoc] = findpeaks (data)
```

Then, I want to take 2% below from that point (`peakVal*0.98`) using the function `find()`. However, I can't to do that because maybe that point does not exist in my vector but a number close to 2% might exist.

I would like to know if you would mind to help me out here. I am stuck with this problem for one week. After this, I will create some error bars, so I need to find a way to solve that.

Comment: Loop through your data and select points that are within (peakVal*0.98) + or - some delta.

Comment: I tried this. However, I failed to clean the index_array. Do you know what I mean?
for example, I am using 


 index = find (y(:,k) > 0.95*CNRmax & y(:,k)< 0.98*CNRmax);

Comment: No. I have no idea what you mean. What language?

Comment: findpeaks does not return *the* maximum, but all local maxima

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x=rand(1,300)*200;
greatest=max(x);
set1=x(x<.98*greatest);
set2=set1(set1>.95*greatest);
closest=max(set2);
```

does this logic work? finding index should be easy after this..

Answer (score 0):

Use logical indexing

```
x=rand(1,300)*200;
val = 0.98;
delta =  0.005;

greatest=max(x);

c = ((val - delta)*greatest < x) & (x < (val + delta)*greatest);
range = x(c);
```